# Unable to get google oauth to work with MERN - 400 bad request - @react-oauth/google

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-oauth

Below is the react form and sections of code thats relevant to this issue

```js
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

const SignUpForm = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const { setAdminId } = useContext(AdminContext);
 
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    /* just the normal submit form function */
  };

  return (
    <>
     
      <Container fluid fill>
        <div className="container-wrapper align-items-center">
          <div className="signup-wrapper">
            <Form className="FormContainer">
       
               
             {/* Normal form input fields are here */}
               
      
              <Button
                className="fullwidth"
                variant="primary"
                onClick={handleSubmit}
              >
                Sign Up !
              </Button>
              or
            </Form>
{/* Below is the part that uses react-oauth/google GoogleLogin*/}
 
          <GoogleLogin
           onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
           let accessToken = credentialResponse.credential
     
            try{
               axios.post(`${apiUrl}/admins/google-register`, {
             googleAccessToken:accessToken
            });
           }
           catch(error){
             console.log("We are facing this error: " + error)
           }
        }}
          onError={() => {
        console.log('Login Failed');
         }}

/*End of  GoogleLogin*/


          />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignUpForm;
```

And below is the route that the above button hits on the server end

```js
//Google register
router.post("/google-register", async (req, res) => {

  if (req.body.googleAccessToken) {
    const {googleAccessToken} = req.body;
   console.log("I am here and got the token right: " + googleAccessToken)
    axios
        .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=${googleAccessToken}`, {
        // headers: {
        //     "Authorization": `Bearer ${googleAccessToken}`
        // }
    })
        .then(async response => {
            const name = response.data.given_name;
            console.log("see if im here in response section")
            // const lastName = response.data.family_name;
            const email = response.data.email;
            // const picture = response.data.picture;

            const existingUser = await Admin.findOne({email})

            if (existingUser) 
                return res.status(400).json({message: "User already exist!"})

            const result = await Admin.create({email, name})

            const token = jwt.sign({
                email: result.email,
                id: result._id
            }, config.get("JWT_SECRET"), {expiresIn: "1h"})

            res
                .status(200)
                .json({result, token})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res
                .status(400)
                .json({message: "Invalid access token!"})
        })

} else {
  console.log("nothing happens")
}
  
});
```

So when I click on 'Google Login button' I get to the google popup and then click on the google account I wanna sign in with, then the following error is displayed in the console
`failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400` & also the error that says `AxiosError:Request failed..`

And I have checked server logs I can see the log up to the 4th line in the server route.

PS: I have also tried with the header code that is commented out which is

```js
    const {googleAccessToken} = req.body;
   console.log("I am here and got the token right: " + googleAccessToken)
    axios
        .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=${googleAccessToken}`, {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${googleAccessToken}`
        }
    })
```

PSS: I have also tried the follwing url but had the same error

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo as below

```js
axios
        .get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo", {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${googleAccessToken}`
        }
    })
```

PSSS: I have also added all the localhost urls in the authorized origins as shown below
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's few things I did to get this resolved.

1. Imported google-oauth-library and wrote a verify function in server file

```js
async function verify(client_id, jwtToken) {
  const client = new OAuth2Client(client_id);
  // Call the verifyIdToken to
  // varify and decode it
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: jwtToken,
      audience: client_id,
  });
  // Get the JSON with all the user info
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  // This is a JSON object that contains
  // all the user info
  ///console.log("payload: " + JSON.stringify(payload))
  return payload;
}
```

2. Use this verify function in the google-register route as shown

```js
//Google register
router.post("/google-register", async (req, res) => {

  if (req.body.response) {
    const {response} = req.body;
   
   verify(response.clientId,response.credential).then(async x=>{
    const email = x.email;
    const name=x.name;
    const existingUser = await Admin.findOne({email})
    
            if (existingUser) {

              return res.status(400).json({message: "User already exist!"})

            }
            const admin = await Admin.create({ email, name})
         
            const payload = {
              admin: {
                _id: admin._id,
              },
            };
      
            jwt.sign(
              payload,
              config.get("jwtSecret"),
              {
                expiresIn: 360000,
              },
              (err, token) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.status(200).json({ token, adminId: admin._id });
              }
            );
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res
                .status(400)
                .json({message: "Invalid access token!"})
        })
 
} else {
  console.log("nothing happens")
}
  
});
```

3. Changed the Admin Model which had required password to false
4. Also to handle the response in the front end just did the following

```js
<GoogleLogin
           onSuccess={ async credentialResponse => {
                    try{ 
                    const res =  await axios.post(`http://localhost:5001/admins/google-register`, {
                    response:credentialResponse
                      });
                       
                    
                       /*console.log(res.data)*/
                      
                    }
                    catch(error){
                      console.log("We are facing this error: " + error)
                    }
              }}
              onError={() => {
                console.log('Login Failed');
              }}
            />
```